# Sitecore EXM Sent Email Campaign Reports are not updating

Tags: exm

I am using Sitecore9Update2 and configuring EXM in localbox.I am able to sent emails but reports are not updating.

[image: EXM Report]
[image: EXM Dashboard]

Comment: @PeteNavarra I am configuring EXM in local and have same key for both settings. [link](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10588/exm-reports-email-campaign-sent-successfully-zero-emails-actually-sent)  This solution is for dispatch server

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is your sitecore setup just 1 IIS site? Or do you have multiple sites for different Sitecore roles? Lastly, verify that xConnect is working. Use this answer to assist with that. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/17213/246